# equivalent to title attribute of anchor html tag in comobobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I say something like:

[image]

in this example was generated using `HTML`.

```
<a href="#" title="The title..">#</a>
```

what's the quick and best way to do something like?
there an equivalent in combobox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's called a tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) class:

```
ToolTip T = new ToolTip();
T.SetToolTip(yourComboBox, "The title...");
```

Comment: Exactly it. Thanks @Adam Rackis. 
another question: it's possible set differents captions for each intem of combobox?

Comment: I don't think so, no... let me check to be sure though

Comment: @TheMask - no, tooltip wants a control on which to set the tooltip - elements inside a ComboBox are not controls.  Sorry.

Comment: Ok. Well..I'II try another way.  Thanks for you help. :)